# PHP script fails causing 500 internal based error with almost no log information

Tags: apache-2.2, php, vps, 500-error

I have a php web application and constantly throws the same error when i try to load its URL , the reason i posted here, is because i get closely to no errors from logs the only one i get in apache error logs is this.

```
[Sat Sep 05 09:47:44 2015] [alert] [client **.**.**.**] 
/home/domain/public_html/invoice/.htaccess: Option FollowSymlinks not allowed here
```

which i dont think is the problem here, cause its an alert and not an error..

server details

- `Apache version 2.2.15`
- `Centos 6.7`
- `PHP 5.3.3`

also `ls -l` lists files as `root:root` at owner:group , the user i make changes from is not `root` its `phoenix:phoenix`, could it be a permission problem?

---

```
    # 1. To use this file, you need to be using Apache with mod_rewrite enabled.
# 2. Rename this file to .htaccess (remove .txt from the end of this file name)

Options +FollowSymlinks
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you would post your .htaccess file in the question. Have you looked at this to see if it points you in the right direction? https://www.virtualmin.com/node/24753

Comment: updated with .htaccess

Comment: @BrianKH could it be that `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` restricts `+FollowSymlinks` since `.htaccess` has `root:root` owner/group and i believe it supposed to be `phoenix:phoenix`?

Comment: Is your application using sym links? If not, you should be able to drop that option. Is your Web server running as phoenix?

Comment: yes it uses symlinks ,   i listed processess and have `root /usr/sbin/httpd` with child  `apache /usr/sbin/httpd` and child `phoenix /usr/bin/php-cgi` so it looks like php-cgi is from phoenix user? isn't that the way it should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you look or make changes to the apache config?
If so you could make sure that AllowOverride All is set for your Virtual Host or Directory.

Comment: AllowOverride is set us `AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` changing or removing `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` would it make a difference?

Comment: Try FollowSymlinks instead of SymLinksIfOwnerMatch.

Comment: yeap that worked out pretty well, script is executing perfectly , imo will stop using apache after this

Comment: Apache is like a girlfriend. Trials and errors before being able to appreciate her